# prime numbers & gcd

Tags: prime-numbers, gcd-and-lcm

I just wanted to make sure about an issue. 
Let $m, p= \text{prime}∈ ℕ-\{0\}$

If $$m≤p^k,$$

does the following exist?
$$\gcd⁡(m,p)≠1⟺ \gcd⁡(m,p^k)≠1$$
and does the restriction $$m≤p^k$$ matter to the existence?

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: EDITED THE MISTAKE

Comment: If $m$ and $p$ are distinct primes then $gcd(m,p)=1$, or if $p=m$  we have  $gcd(p,m)=m$ and $gcd(m,p^{k})=m$ for $k\geq 1$.

Comment: @Äres can you see the edit pls? thanks!

Comment: Sorry I can't see what you've edited.

Comment: @Äres m is not necessarily a prime, only p

Comment: By the dupe: $\,a_1,a_2,\ldots a_k\,$ are all coprime to $m\iff $ their product is coprime to $m$. Yours is special case all $\,a_i = p\ \ $

Comment: @BillDubuque TY!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$m \le p^k$ is not required. If gcd$(m,p) \neq1$ then $m$ and $p$ must share a common factor, because the only factor of $p$ is $p$ (and one, but we will not need to worry about that) then at least $p$ must be a factor of $m$. If we now look at gcd$(m,p^k)$ $p^k$ will have a factor of $p$ and we already know that $m$ has a factor of $p$ and therefore gcd$(m,p^k) \neq1$ as it must at least be equal to $p$. At no point have we required $m \le p^k$.

Comment: what about the other direction?

Comment: What do you mean?